# I am having trouble in passing ssl certificate on webview in ios

Tags: ios, ssl-certificate

I am using uiwebview. I have applied ssl pinning to AFNetworking API calls.But I am unable to pass certificate pinning on webview. I need to know how to pass ssl certificate pinning on webview redirection.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [LivefyreAPICalls sslpinning:manager :@"certificate.com" :@"cer"];

NSString *content =[request.URL absoluteString];
    NSArray *urlComponents = [content componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];

for (NSString *keyValuePair in urlComponents)
{
    NSArray *pairComponents = [keyValuePair componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
    NSString *key = [[pairComponents firstObject] stringByRemovingPercentEncoding];
    NSString *value = [[pairComponents lastObject] stringByRemovingPercentEncoding];
    [queryStringDictionary setObject:value forKey:key];
}

if ([queryStringDictionary valueForKey:@"id_token"]) {
    [[UserNetwork manager] setUserFromSessionFromToken:[queryStringDictionary valueForKey:@"id_token"] :nil];
    if ([UserNetwork manager].networkUsers.count >=1) {

        SettingsViewController *settingsView=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SettingsViewController"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:settingsView animated:NO];
    }else{
        LiveBlogsTableViewController *blogView=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"liveblog"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:blogView animated:YES];
    }
}
return YES;
}
```

Comment: what you have tried? Can you share code

Comment: @Shabirjan i blocked on ssl_pinning.Can you please help,If you know....?

Comment: hi are you available for small teamviewer session

Comment: @Shabirjan i don't have team viewer.Can we connect on skype...?

Comment: cant you install teamviewer?

Comment: BTW check my answer as well

Comment: @Shabirjan ok. i will install

Answer (score 1):

`UiWebView` does not expose any direct API to that, but it can still be implemented using NSURLProtocol, which gives you the ability to validate the certificate of all outgoing network requests. It does take a lot of work though, and a better solution is to use `WKWebView`, which provides an explicit way of doing pinning via the `WKNavigationDelegate's` `webView:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:completionHandler:` (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKNavigationDelegate_Ref/index.html).

There are more details in the "Pinning in Webviews" section of this article: https://datatheorem.github.io/TrustKit/getting-started.html and it's also a library for implement public key pinning in iOS Apps.

Check out this link as well :

https://github.com/antekarin/ssl-pinning-swift

Check this blog as well :
http://ryandavis.io/allowing-uiwebview-to-accept-self-signed-certificates/

Comment: Already i tried trustkit. It pinned Direct api calls.But it is not working on webview.

Comment: try using WKWebView

Comment: No with WKWebView

Comment: i tried with wkwebview, I got navigations.i pinnied one of the navigation but no use.

Comment: Can you please paste the sample code here which i have to write in webView:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:completionHandler

Comment: Yah exactly i am using same code for direct api calls using afnetwork in ios. But it is not applying on webview request.

Comment: http://ryandavis.io/allowing-uiwebview-to-accept-self-signed-certificates/ check this

Comment: i tried with wkwebview. But i am getting an unsupported url error while i implemented arbitrary load = YES in info.plist.  Can you help on this please, If you know.

Comment: i did pinning successfully using wkwebview.Thanks bro. I am using the same process on another url,But that url contains oauth2 process.I am unable to pin the this oauth2 url.

Comment: can we do personal chat for some other doubts otherthan this issue.pls